# Magnific Popup showing first item only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup

New to using jQuery and Magnific Popup - I have a grid of images, and when you click on an image I want magnific popup to display a div with information relevant to the particular image.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="#test-popup" class="open-popup-link"><img class="object open-popup-link" src="i/objects/8/a.jpg" alt="3D Printed Object"></a>
        <div id="test-popup" class="popup mfp-hide">
            <div class="maker-profile">
                <img class="headshot" src="i/maker.jpg" alt="Designer of 3D printed object">
                <h2>A, aged 8</h2>
                <h3>Who are you?</h3>
                <h3>What inspires you?</h3>
                <h3>What do you like most about design?</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="#test-popup" class="open-popup-link"><img class="object open-popup-link" src="i/objects/8/ab.jpg" alt="3D Printed Object"></a>
        <div id="test-popup" class="popup mfp-hide">
            <div class="maker-profile">
                <img class="headshot" src="i/maker.jpg" alt="Designer of 3D printed object">
                <h2>Ab, aged 8</h2>
                <h3>Who are you?</h3>
                <h3>What inspires you?</h3>
                <h3>What do you like most about design?</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="#test-popup" class="open-popup-link"><img class="object open-popup-link" src="i/objects/8/f.jpg" alt="3D Printed Object"></a>
        <div id="test-popup" class="popup mfp-hide">
            <div class="maker-profile">
                <img class="headshot" src="i/maker.jpg" alt="Designer of 3D printed object">
                <h2>F, aged 8</h2>
                <h3>Who are you?</h3>
                <h3>What inspires you?</h3>
                <h3>What do you like most about design?</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's the jQuery -

```
$(function() {
 $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type:'inline',
  midClick: true
 })
});
```

What's happening is when you click on ANY of my images in the grid (img.object) Magnific Popup only displays the div (.test-popup) from the first grid-item.

Answer (score 2):

That is because all your `.popup` elements have the same `id` (*"test-popup"*).
So when you are trying to target them with `<a href="#test-popup">` you end up finding the first one always. (*`id` must be unique in the page*).

If you change the `id`s to make them unique, you will have no problem.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="#test-popup-1" class="open-popup-link"><img class="object open-popup-link" src="i/objects/8/a.jpg" alt="3D Printed Object"></a>
        <div id="test-popup-1" class="popup mfp-hide">
            <div class="maker-profile">
                <img class="headshot" src="i/maker.jpg" alt="Designer of 3D printed object">
                <h2>A, aged 8</h2>
                <h3>Who are you?</h3>
                <h3>What inspires you?</h3>
                <h3>What do you like most about design?</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="#test-popup-2" class="open-popup-link"><img class="object open-popup-link" src="i/objects/8/ab.jpg" alt="3D Printed Object"></a>
        <div id="test-popup-2" class="popup mfp-hide">
            <div class="maker-profile">
                <img class="headshot" src="i/maker.jpg" alt="Designer of 3D printed object">
                <h2>Ab, aged 8</h2>
                <h3>Who are you?</h3>
                <h3>What inspires you?</h3>
                <h3>What do you like most about design?</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="#test-popup-3" class="open-popup-link"><img class="object open-popup-link" src="i/objects/8/f.jpg" alt="3D Printed Object"></a>
        <div id="test-popup-3" class="popup mfp-hide">
            <div class="maker-profile">
                <img class="headshot" src="i/maker.jpg" alt="Designer of 3D printed object">
                <h2>F, aged 8</h2>
                <h3>Who are you?</h3>
                <h3>What inspires you?</h3>
                <h3>What do you like most about design?</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh perfect! Thank you.  I am also noticing that I see this error in the console "uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function" any idea why?

Comment: @hannahcreative can't help without seeing the JS code that is relevant to the error. If you have a link to see it in action ..